# Why this code which uses windsor Castle doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have an MVC application which uses Windsor everywhere and it works fine everywhere with Windsor Castle, but now I am adding a new code into it and it is not working properly.
I configured Castle with the following code:

```
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IFileUploadService>().ImplementedBy<FileUploadService>().DependsOn(Parameter.ForKey("x").Eq(
            "test")).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
    }
```

The FileUploadService is defined as follow:

```
  public class FileUploadService : IFileUploadService
{



            public FileUploadService(string x)
    {
      // use x        
    }
 }
```

I am sure that the installer line is calling (Debug shows that the line is runs at the start of application.

I have a Controller which is defined as follow:

```
   public FileUploadController(IConfiguration Configuration, IFileUploadService fileUploadService)
    {
        this.Configuration = Configuration;
        this.fileUploadService = fileUploadService;
    }
```

When I run this application, I am getting this error:

```
   Can't create component 'FileUploadService' as it has dependencies to be satisfied. 
   FileUploadService is waiting for the following dependencies: 

    Keys (components with specific keys)
    - x which was not registered.
```

What is the problem? I have similar code which they are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:
The above code works on Windsor 3.x but my application uses 2.5.
the correct way of doing this in version 2.5 is as follow:

```
  container.Register(Component.For<IFileUploadService>().ImplementedBy<FileUploadService>().Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("x").Eq(
        "test")).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```